# Selecting variables one by one in glm

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I have the following example dataset

```
set.seed(2001)
n <- 100
Y <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X1 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.4,0.5))
X2 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))
X3 <- c(0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

dat <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2,X3)
```

I fit a logistic regression model to each of the variable to rank them based on residual difference (highest to lowest). To simplify I got the rank as X3,X1 and X2. Then, I fit a second order model as follows and again calculate the res_dif  :

```
mod1 <- glm(Y~X3+X1, family=binomial, data=dat)
mod1$null.deviance-mod1$deviance
mod2 <- glm(Y~X3+X2, family=binomial,data=dat)
mod2$null.deviance-mod2$deviance
```

Again, I will rank the model based on res_dif (highest to lowest). So here, I choose mod2. From there I will fit the third order model as follows :

```
mod3 <- glm(Y~X3+X2+X1, family=binomial, data=dat)
mod3$null.deviance-mod3$deviance
```

Basically, this continues until it fit the maximum number of variables that you have in the data. Since my actual data is dealing with 100 of variables, I wonder how can I apply this using loop function. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `MASS::stepAIC` or `leaps::regsubsets` ?

Comment: But they were using R2, AIC, BIC or Cp as their selection critieria.

Comment: Perhaps `glmulti` would work or `bestglm` - haven't tried it though.

Comment: I thought regsubsets is only for linear model. I will go through the package again to see whether I can fit family=binomial in the function. Thanks @rbm

Comment: As above, i'd try `glmulti` or `bestglm`. AIC/BIC are usually used to evaluate/compare models. Also check http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/how-to-do-logistic-regression-subset-selection - discussed whys and hows.